# How to Pass Data from React Native to Passport.js FacebookTokenStrategy Callback?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, passport.js, passport-facebook

I'm trying to pass data like deviceID to Passport.js FacebookTokenStrategy callback.

I tried using `req._toParam`, but it is not working, seems like it's deprecated.

server router file

```
authRouter.post(
    '/facebook/token',
      (req, res, next) => {
        req._toParam = req.user.uniqueDeviceID;
        passport.authenticate('facebook-token')(req, res, next)
      },
      (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
      }
  );
```

server passport strategy file

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookTokenStrategy(
        {
            clientID: keys.facebookAppID,
            clientSecret: keys.facebookAppSecret
        },
        async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {  
                 console.log(req._toParam); 
                 //how to pass react-native-device-info deviceID to this callback?
              }
       )
)
```

react native client side

```
const res = await server.post(`/auth/facebook/token?access_token=${tokenData.accessToken}&uniqueDeviceID=${DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()}`);
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `passReqToCallback: true` in FacebookTokenStrategy to pass the request to strategy callback and using [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.query) to retrieve the query string data `uniqueDeviceID=${DeviceInfo.getUniqueId()}`.

```
passport.use(
    new FacebookTokenStrategy(
        {
            clientID: keys.facebookAppID,
            clientSecret: keys.facebookAppSecret,
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {  
                 console.log(req.query.uniqueDeviceID);
        }
    )
);
```

Thus skipping the need to forward request from router to strategy callback.

```
authRouter.post(
    '/facebook/token',     
    passport.authenticate('facebook-token'),
      (req, res) => {
        res.send(req.user);
      }
  );
```